# Can I use [VerifyExists(TriggerEvents.AfterClick)] on a web element different than the one I am verifying?

Tags: c#, atata

I have several elements that are NOT displayed until I click a button.

My question is:

Can I use an attribute like

```
[WaitFor(Until.Visible,TriggerEvents.AfterClick)]
```

or

```
[VerifyExists(TriggerEvents.AfterClick)]
```

to wait for the verification until I click the button in order the expected elements to be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options.

**Use WaitForElement trigger**

```
[WaitForElement(WaitBy.Id, "some-id", Until.Visible)]
[WaitForElement(WaitBy.XPath, "some-xpath", Until.Visible)]
public Button<_> DoSomething { get; private set; }
```

**Extract waiting to separate method and use InvokeMethod trigger**

```
[InvokeMethod(nameof(WaitForSomeElements), TriggerEvents.AfterClick)]
public Button<_> DoSomething { get; private set; }

private void WaitForSomeElements()
{
    SomeControl.Wait(Until.Visible);
    AnotherControl.Wait(Until.Visible);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Yevgeniy!
"Extract waiting to separate method and use InvokeMethod trigger" worked for me.